# Mongoose select: false not working on location nested object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want the `location` field of my schema to be hidden by default.
I added `select: false` property to it, but it is always returned when selecting documents...

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

cellphone: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
  unique: true,
},

location: {
  'type': {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
    default: 'Point'
   },
   coordinates: [Number],
   select: false, <-- here
   },
});

userSchema.index({location: '2dsphere'});
```

**When calling :**

`User.find({ }, function(err, result){
  console.log(result[0]);
});`

**the output is :**

```
 {  
    cellphone: '+33656565656',
    location: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [Object] } <-- Shouldn't
 }
```

**EDIT :**  Explanation (thanks to @alexmac)

SchemaType select option must be applied to the field options not a type. In you example you've defined a complex type Location and added select option to a type.

Comment: What about findOne, does it return it or not?

Comment: Problem has been solved. And yes, findOne returned it as well  :)

Comment: Would be nice if you shared your solution. @MalteseFalcon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should firstly create `locationSchema` and after that use schema type with `select: false`:

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    'type': {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
        default: 'Point'
       },
       coordinates: [Number]
    }
});

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    location: {
      type: locationSchema,
      select: false
    }
});
```

Comment: We are close, coordinates aren't shown anymore, but the rest of location is : `"location": { "type": "Point" }`

Note: I added select: false to location too.

Comment: Ok, I thought you want to hide only `coordinates` field, if you want to hide `location` completely, you should define it schema for it and use it as type.

Comment: Can you just remove the bracket after `coordinates`, and replace the `;` after locationSchema by a `,`.
Finally, could you just explain why select attribute doesn't direclty work within nested objects ? Why do we have to declare external schemas ?

Comment: SchemaType `select` option must be applied to the field options not a type. In you example you've defined a complex type `Location` and added `select` option to a type.